# How can i show page loader when 2 or more api call is there?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

basically i created 1 state `[isLoading, setIsLoading]=useState(false)`

i have 3 apis that need to call.

```
const api1 = ()=>{
 setIsLoading(true)
 callApi()
 setIsLoading(false)
}

const api2 = ()=>{
 setIsLoading(true)
 callApi()
 setIsLoading(false)
}

const api3 = ()=>{
 setIsLoading(true)
 callApi()
 setIsLoading(false)
}
```

I call those 3 functions in `useEffect()` .
using axios for calling the apis,
Whenever any one of the api call is success it will set the `setIsLoading()` to false. so loading animation is stopped.
Still other 2 apis are not completed.

Basically i need to stop the loader when all the api calls are done.

In Ui part im just doing `isLoading && <Loader />`

- One solution is creating 3 states and using like `(isLoading1 || isLoading2 || isLoading3) && <Loader />`

But i dont like to create multiple states like this.

Any better way to handle this Loading Animation?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a state variable like:

```
loadingCounter
```

then in each function before the `callApi` increment it, and when `callApi` is done, decrement it.

So if `loadingCounter > 0` it means data is loading from somewhere still.

Or look into `Promise.all`

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch your API's with one call using Promise.all
and wait for promises to be resolved

```
setLoading(true);
const promise1 = callAPI();
const promise2 = callAPI();
const promise3 = callAPI();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  setLoading(false)
});
```

if you want to handle API fail call

```
Promise.all([promise1.catch((error) => error), promise2.catch((error) => error),promise3.catch((error) => error)])
.then(
  (values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); 
    console.error(values[1]); 
    console.error(values[2]); 
  }
);
```

Comment: How to handle if any API call failed,

Comment: @MuhammadJaan, Use Promise.allSettled([promise1, promise2]).then()